# Onde habilito a keychain do IOS no xamarin/vs?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin-forms

eu estou usando xamarin forms
e tentando usar xamarin.Auth para salvar informações no banco de dados do dispositivo..Para android fiz isso e tudo certo...
Mas quando rodo o IOS tenho esse erro...

```
> Xamarin.Auth.AccountStoreException: SaveAsync error = error = Could not save account to KeyChain: -34018
Add Empty Entitlements.plist 
 File /+ New file /+ iOS /+ Entitlements.plist
SecKeyChain.Add returned : -34018
1. Add Keychain Access Groups to the Entitlements file.
2. Turn on the Keychain Sharing switch in the Capabilities section in the app.
```

Estou usando essas linhas no code behind:

```
        account.Properties.Add("teste2", "1");
        account.Properties.Add("teste1", "usereee");
        AccountStore.Create().Save(account, "clastech_montana");
```

[image]

Isso é tudo o que eu fiz até agora... Eu já pesquisei muito e acho que não sei ligar a keychain do ios ou se eu fiz algo errado... parece q tenho q ligar na minha ios developer account...me inscrevi la, mas não tem a opção de credenciais (credentials and id - algo assim) que eles dizem que teria.
alguém pode ajudar?!

[image]

Não existe lugar para ligar a chave aqui